# realloc fails in visual studio with big values

Tags: c, visual-studio, realloc

When I run this code in VS2013 it fails saying "realloc test.exe has triggered a breakpoint." and I have no Idea why, any ideas?(although if I try to realloc small values it will be ok)

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
    char *big = malloc(100);
    char *c;
    //c = malloc(INT_MAX);// this line works perfectly, on a 32bit build it will be = NULL
    c = (char *)realloc(big, INT_MAX);//this one triggers a breakpoint!(or that's what visual studio says)
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I'm building it for a 32bit target which by VS's default settings will not allow access to more than 2 Gib(almost), so it should fail here but just by returning a NULL pointer not triggering a breakpoint!

note : I'm building it as RELEASE

Comment: You don't have enough _contiguous_ memory.

Comment: even so, shouldn't it just return NULL?

Comment: @user730033 Your code (built with VS2010) does return NULL for me. Is this the exact program that fails for you?

Comment: @simonc yes it is.Is your target build 64 bit?

Comment: @herohuyongtao, it's c, can't use vector!

Comment: @user730033 I'm using a slightly older compiler but am building for 32-bit

Comment: @simonc I really have no idea why. I tried it on VS10 on a different machine and same error, but it offered more insight saying "heap corruption"!

Comment: @esihaj: Is this the actual code, line for line, which causes the error?  If it is I say you should write a bug report.  If it's not then you're likely corrupting memory somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The debug breakpoint is triggered by the debug Windows heap manager.  Even if you use the release CRT, if you start the process under a debugger, the Windows heap will enable debug checks.  You can disable these debug checks by defining the environment variable `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP` to `1` before you start debugging your process (or in the debug settings for your project).

The CRT debug heap also has a similar check that (by default) asserts on extremely large allocations, but this check is only present in the debug CRT (the release CRT has practically no logic in its heap implementation--it just calls to the operating system heap functions).

We're investigating options for fixing both of these issues for future releases.  In the meantime, if your code is tripping over the debug breakpoint, I'd recommend disabling the Windows debug heap by defining the aforementioned environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

It will return a null pointer if failed to allocate.

- from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc

  > Return value
  >
  > Pointer to the beginning of newly allocated memory or null pointer if error has occurred. The pointer must be deallocated with std::free().
- from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

  > Return Value
  >
  > On success, a pointer to the memory block allocated by the function.
  >   The type of this pointer is always void*, which can be cast to the desired type of data pointer in order to be dereferenceable.
  >   If the function failed to allocate the requested block of memory, a null pointer is returned.

Comment: Well it should fail(not enough memory), not stop program with a breakpoint

Comment: @esihaj If you're running in debug, I'd be shocked if it didn't break. If you're running in release-mode *and* using the secure CRT, check the documentation from MS, as it may likely abort in that condition as well.

Comment: Neither one, release build without crtdebug/secure

Comment: @WhozCraig: Calling `abort` would completely break testing your code for this scenario.  Anyway, the docs for [_realloc_dbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydfebz1c.aspx) state only that it sets `errno` to `ENOMEM` if the allocation fails.  Even so, he says release, so... bug in the VS standard library or he isn't showing us his real code.

Answer (score 0):

Run an test to see what the maximum number of bytes (GBs) you can allocate on your machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GIGA_BYTE (1024 * 1024 * 1024)

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long mallocSize = 0, numGigaBytes = 0;
    void *mallocMemory = NULL;

    do
    {
        mallocSize += GIGA_BYTE;
        numGigaBytes = mallocSize / GIGA_BYTE;
        mallocMemory = malloc(mallocSize);
        if(mallocMemory)
        {
            printf("Dynamically allocated %llu GBs\n", numGigaBytes);
            free(mallocMemory);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Failed to allocate %llu GBs\n", numGigaBytes);
            break;
        }
    }
    while(true);

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine I encountered the following maximum:

> ...
>   Dynamically allocated 17 GBs
>   Dynamically allocated 18 GBs
>   Failed to allocate 19 GBs

Comment: Only 1 GB (the real value is just a little below 2 GB(1.9 or something), this is visual studio restricting amount of heap memory a program can allocate

Comment: Interesting approach, but why use `unsigned long long mallocSize`  instead of `size_t mallocSize`?  `size_t` is the largest integer for  `malloc()`.  Or use `void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);` as the product may be larger than `size_t` and still allocate successfully.

Comment: @chux Through it together quickly without verifying some things.  You're right, it would be better with `size_t`.